# Elixir EntityCollection.remove() doesn't work

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm trying to remove a certain `Entity` from the collection in a `EntityCollection`, which is not working, results in an exception: `list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Code excerpt as follows:

`user.platformSubscriptions.remove(platform)`

The platform variable is in fact in the platformSubscriptions collection.

Comment: `platform` must not be in the `platformSubscriptions` collection.  Please post a stack trace and additional code that will allow us to help you.

Comment: @wberry thanks, indeed you are correct, but more specifically they are not of the same **instance** even though the objects are from the same record. Hence the default comparator would not find a match in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was probably because there was no proper comparator function for the platform object. So the solution is to loop through `platformSubscriptions` to find a match for `platform` by comparing the `id` field:

```
for subedPlat in user.platformSubscriptions:
    if subedPlat.id == platform.user.platformSubscriptions.remove(subedPlat)
```